# Find the index of a list which is subset in a list of list

Tags: python, list, subset

I have two **very large** list of list (order of 5 millions).

For instance:

1) The first list, a, contains always list of 8 elements.

2) The second list, b, contains always list of 4 elements.

For each list in b there may be more than one subsets but this is not a problem.

```
a=[[0 1 10 9 369 370 379 378],[1 2 11 10 370 371 380 379]..[[0 1 10 9 365 370 379 400]]

b=[[0 1 370 369],[1 2 371 370], ......]
```

**I'd like to know for each list in b the index of the list in a that contains all the its element.**

For instance: I know that "b[0]=[ 0   1 370 369]" is a subset of "a[0]=[0 1 10 9 369 370 379 378]" because all the elements in b[0] are contained in a[0]. The same things for b[1] being a subset of a[1].

So  I'd like to have an output of this kind:  c=[[0],[1].......].

If there is more than one subset I should get something like: c=[[0],[1]....[20,19].....]

My problem is that my code is too too slow:

```
index=[]
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if set(b[i])<set(a[j]):
        print b[i]
        print a[j]
        print j
        index.append([j]) #index in a
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
[  0   1 370 369]
[  0   1  10   9 369 370 379 378]
0

[  1   2 371 370]
[  1   2  11  10 370 371 380 379]
1

.
.
[369 370 739 738]
[369 370 379 378 738 739 748 747]
320
.
.
```

At the end of the loop len(index)=len(b) because I know for sure that each list in b is always a subset of a.

It takes up to 30/40 seconds for each iteration.

I am sure there is a more pythonic way to perform the same loop, how can I speed it up?

Thank you

Comment: Start by converting `a` and `b` to lists of sets (instead of lists of lists). That will save you `n^2` set constructor calls.

Comment: also(not related to the question at hand), `index.append([j])` will append a one item list every single time `b[i]` is a subset of `a[j]`. unless Im mistaken, you want instead a single list of all the indices that `b[i]<a[j]` which means you need to have something to append to `index[i]` if a list has already been started or append to `index` if not

Comment: maybe I should have written: set(b[i])<set(a[j])==True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a dict showing which lists in `a` contain each number:

```
import collections
number_locations = collections.defaultdict(set)
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    for num in l:
        number_locations[num].add(i)
```

Then for each list in `b`, look up where in `a` its elements can be found and take the set intersection to find which elements of `a` contain all 4 numbers:

```
index = [set.intersection(*[number_locations[num] for num in l]) for l in b]
```

This produces a list of sets; if you really need lists, you can call `list` on the items, or `sorted` to get sorted lists of indices.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This has significantly speed up the loop, however I  have noticed that if I use the full length of list a my PC struggle to keep up and crashes. I believe this is because of large ram memory used to store list a. I was wondering if there is anyway to improve the code on this side. Thanks.

Comment: @user5587564: It'd depend on where lists a and b are coming from. You could try working with chunks of list a at a time, or iterate over list a destructively by `pop`ping from the end to build the dict if you don't need the list after this.